# What would be the proper way to shorten these lines

Tags: python, pep8

pylint keeps yelling at me about these long lines and im trying to be PEP8 compliant. I have tried a few different methods but non that where zen enough
for pylint.

```
def arg_handler():
    ''' Process command-line args '''

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='PoC for the TCP/32764 backdoor.\n'\
        'see https://github.com/elvanderb/TCP-32764 for more details')

    parser.add_argument('--ip', type=str, nargs='?', help='routers IP', default='192.168.1.1')
    parser.add_argument('--port', type=int, nargs='?', help='port to use', default=32764)
    command_group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    command_group.add_argument('--is_vuln',help='tells you if the router is vulnerable or not (default)', action="store_true")
    command_group.add_argument('--shell', help='gives you a root shell on the router', action="store_true")
    command_group.add_argument('--execute', type=str, nargs='?', help='run a command and dump straight to stdout', default='')
    command_group.add_argument('--print_conf', help='pretty print router\'s configuration', action="store_true")
    command_group.add_argument('--get_credentials', help='gets credentials', action="store_true")
    command_group.add_argument('--get_var', type=str, nargs='?', metavar='var_name', help='get router\'s configuration variable')
    command_group.add_argument('--set_var', type=str, nargs='?', metavar='var_name=val', help='set router\'s configuration variable')
    command_group.add_argument('--message', type=int, nargs='?', help='message to send', choices=range(1, 14))
    command_group.add_argument('--send_file', type=str, nargs='?', help='file to send')
    command_group.add_argument('--send_file2', type=str, nargs='?', help='file to send, using echo -n -e')
    parser.add_argument('--payload', type=str, nargs='?', help='message\'s payload', default='')
    parser.add_argument('--timeout', type=int, nargs='?', help='connexion timeout in seconds', default=1)
    parser.add_argument('--remote-filename', type=str, nargs='?', help='remote filename in /tmp when copying', default="upload")
    return parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would you properly break this line to match pep8 rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931297/how-would-you-properly-break-this-line-to-match-pep8-rules)

Comment: don't, it's vastly more readable when each argument occupies one line.
Place the help text into a variable, and manage their lengths to keep the add_argument statement more clean.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the longest line you have

```
command_group.add_argument('--set_var', type=str, nargs='?', metavar='var_name=val', help='set router\'s configuration variable')
```

Now first, split the commas into lines

```
command_group.add_argument(
    '--set_var',
    type=str,
    nargs='?',
    metavar='var_name=val',
    help='set router\'s configuration variable'
)
```

And that should be PEP8 compliant.

If you have an argument that's too long, then split the string (i.e. if your help message is too long)

EDIT: Probably better to format it like so (Previously had some terrible formatted string)

```
some_help_message=(
    'blahblahblah'
    'moreblahblahblah'
    'evenmoreblahblahblah'
    'wowsohelpful'
)
```

Comment: C: 17, 0: Wrong hanging indentation (add 6 spaces).
  type=str,
  ^     | (bad-continuation)

Comment: help is a builtin function, so that naming convention will not work, also only the 'blahblahblah' string is stored in your `help` variable.

Comment: @flevinkelming the help message was more for passing into the command. Not to be used separately. Obviously if you're going to use it outside of the parameter, you should name is something other than help.

Comment: @RickyWilson I used a PEP8 checker, and it says that what I posted was fine. Are you using pylint by chance? If so, which one?

Comment: Pylint says this is not compliant  with pep8 
https://pastebin.com/RegDbLj9

Comment: I always use pylint

Comment: @RickyWilson your ending parenthesis is wrongly indented. Also, all the parameters should be 4 space indented from the initial function call.

Comment: @xNinjaKittyx sorry, I didn't see you were specifying the kwarg for `.add_argument` - whoops!

Answer (score 1):

As a an example with what you have implemented:

```
command_group.add_argument(
    '--is_vuln',
    help='tells you if the router is vulnerable or not (default)',
    action="store_true"
)
```

If I'm not mistaken, anything within 79 characters per line is PEP8 compliant.

Additionally, when a string exceeds 79 characters, you can format it like so:

```
long_string = ("thisisanextremelylongstring"
               "thatissolongiamputtingiton"
               "anotherline")
```